# What does mean CompositionLocal properties should be prefixed with Local?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've used `compositionLocalOf` as follows:

```
val SoundSelectionProvider = compositionLocalOf<String> { error("No value provided") }
var sound = "Option 1"
```

Android Studio shows a hint:

> CompositionLocal properties should be prefixed with Local

what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just that as a matter of convention, the names of the providers should **start** with the word, "Local". So, just rename "SoundSelectionProvider" to "LocalSoundSelectionProvider" and the error will go away.

Comment: Just like Composable names should start with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: CompositionLocal objects or constants are usually prefixed with
> Local to allow better discoverability with auto-complete in the IDE.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal

It means as in description for discoverability your `SoundSelectionProvider` is better to be named with a prefix with ***Local*** such as `LocalSoundSelection`